# How to sort notification channels in system settings on android O

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have preset order of notification channels, that can be change. How to change order of notification channels? I try to sort by channel_id and channel_name, but it is not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was error in my solution. I try to add number of channel on start of channel id for sorting. So i had this:

```
56_server_channel_id
78_server_channel_id
155_server_channel_id
9998_default_app_channel_id
9999_default_app_channel_id
```

But because of missing leading zeros, it sorted not as i expected. So, right solution is:

```
0056_server_channel_id
0078_server_channel_id
0155_server_channel_id
9998_default_app_channel_id
9999_default_app_channel_id
```

Comment: it worked for me, too, but this sorting by channel id looks like an undocumented behaviour, so I wonder a bit whether this may change; although in that case perhaps Google adds support for explicit sorting

Comment: @levavare agree, i couldn't find any doc