# How to change the order of notification channels (categories) alphabetically in Android O system settings?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a set of notification channels created. After loaded onto the phone, I realised the order of the channels are not sorted alphabetically in system settings. Is there a way to sort the channels (categories) alphabetically?

I have read and search on the documentation but could not find a solution. I have also search here but only have this thread ([How to sort notification channels in system settings on android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854990/how-to-sort-notification-channels-in-system-settings-on-android-o)) which does not provide a solution either.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: In android emulator (Android Pie, Api Level 29), notification channels are sorted by their channel-ID.

Comment: Does it only apply to android pie and above? Does that it cannot be sorted by ourselves?